# Como hago para que desaparezcan los círculos cuando vuelven y que siempre sean de un solo color

Tags: java

Mi problema esta en que cuando inicio el código me dibuja inicialmente en color negro para después pasar al azul.

Yo quiero que solo los dibuje de un color para posteriormente cuando se haga click cambie al color designado (esto es después).

Además no consigo hacer que cuando el circulo ha llegado al máximo se borren mientras van disminuyendo de tamaño.

```
int N1; //the number of rings
int N2; //timer


int mX; //mX is current mouseX position
int mY; //mY is current mouseY position



int Dstep; // the increment at which the diameter will increase
int Astep; // the increment and which alpha will decrease
int Alp; //alpha value
int Dia; //diameter value

int inc = 1;


void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  colorMode(HSB, 100);
  noFill();
  strokeWeight(2);
  smooth();

  frameRate(20);

  N1 = 20;
  N2 = 0;
  Alp = 100;
  Dia = 10;
}



void mouseClicked() {

  mX = mouseX;
  mY = mouseY;
  Math();
  Dia = 10;
  Alp = 100;
  N2=0;
  stroke(50, 100, 100, Alp);
}

void draw() {

  N2 = N2 + inc;
  if (N2>N1) {
    inc = -1;
    stroke(10, 10, 10, Alp);
  } 
  else if (N2<1) {
    inc = 1;
    stroke(50, 100, 100, Alp);

  }
  Ellipse();


}


void Math() {
  Dstep = 20; //determinar aqui el diametro que queramos alcanzar
  Astep = 100/N1;
}

void Ellipse() {

  ellipse(width/2, height/2, N2*12, N2*12);
  strokeWeight(N2/7+0.5);

  println("N2:"+N2);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Puede probar esto y me comenta es que no se, que color es el que quiere primero.

```
int N1; //the number of rings
int N2; //timer


int mX; //mX is current mouseX position
int mY; //mY is current mouseY position



int Dstep; // the increment at which the diameter will increase
int Astep; // the increment and which alpha will decrease
int Alp; //alpha value
int Dia; //diameter value

int inc = 1;

boolean test = false;   //se añade

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  colorMode(HSB, 100);
  noFill();
  strokeWeight(2);
  smooth();

  frameRate(20);

  N1 = 20;
  N2 = 0;
  Alp = 100;
  Dia = 10;
}



void mouseClicked() {

  mX = mouseX;
  mY = mouseY;
  Math();
  Dia = 10;
  Alp = 100;
  N2=0;
  stroke(50, 100, 100, Alp);   //puede cambiar para un color u otro
  //stroke(10, 10, 10, Alp);   //puede cambiar para un color u otro
  test = true;                 //se añade
}

void draw() {

  N2 = N2 + inc;
  if (N2>N1) {
    inc = -1;
    if(test){                        //se añade if con test boolean
        stroke(50, 100, 100, Alp);   //puede cambiar para un color u otro
        //stroke(10, 10, 10, Alp);   //puede cambiar para un color u otro
    }else{
        stroke(10, 10, 10, Alp);     //puede cambiar para un color u otro
        //stroke(50, 100, 100, Alp); //puede cambiar para un color u otro
    }
  } 
  else if (N2<1) {
    inc = 1;
    if(test){                        //se añade if con test boolean
        stroke(50, 100, 100, Alp);   //puede cambiar para un color u otro
        //stroke(10, 10, 10, Alp);   //puede cambiar para un color u otro
    }else{
        stroke(10, 10, 10, Alp);     //puede cambiar para un color u otro
        //stroke(50, 100, 100, Alp); //puede cambiar para un color u otro
    }
  }
  Ellipse();


}


void Math() {
  Dstep = 20; //determinar aqui el diametro que queramos alcanzar
  Astep = 100/N1;
}

void Ellipse() {

  ellipse(width/2, height/2, N2*12, N2*12);
  strokeWeight(N2/7+0.5);

  println("N2:"+N2);

}
```

---

### Update:

Le conteste sobre la primera parte pero no recorde esta hasta que lo volvi a leer

> Además no consigo hacer que cuando el circulo ha llegado al máximo se
>   borren mientras van disminuyendo de tamaño.

lo unico que se me ocurre es jugar con el `background`, `stroke`, y con el `strokeWeight`, porque no creo que usted quierea usar `clear()`, le dejo un ejemplo de lo que le digo espero le ayude.

```
int N1; //the number of rings
int N2; //timer


int mX; //mX is current mouseX position
int mY; //mY is current mouseY position



int Dstep; // the increment at which the diameter will increase
int Astep; // the increment and which alpha will decrease
int Alp; //alpha value
int Dia; //diameter value

int inc = 1;

boolean test = false;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  colorMode(HSB, 100);
  bg = color(180, 50, 50); // se añade

  noFill();
  strokeWeight(2);
  smooth();

  frameRate(20);

  N1 = 20;
  N2 = 0;
  Alp = 100;
  Dia = 10;

  background(bg); //se añade
}



void mouseClicked() {

  mX = mouseX;
  mY = mouseY;
  Math();
  Dia = 10;
  Alp = 100;
  N2=0;
  stroke(50, 100, 100, Alp);
  //stroke(10, 10, 10, Alp);
  test = true;
}

void draw() {

  N2 = N2 + inc;
  if (N2>N1) {
        println("sub ");
    inc = -1;
    if(test){
        //stroke(50, 100, 100, Alp);
        //stroke(10, 10, 10, Alp);
        stroke(180, 50, 50, Alp); //se añade este es el color que usa el bg
    }else{
        //stroke(10, 10, 10, Alp);
        //stroke(50, 100, 100, Alp);
        stroke(180, 50, 50, Alp); //se añade este es el color que usa el bg
    }
    //clear();
  } 
  else if (N2<1) {

    inc = 1;
    if(test){
        stroke(50, 100, 100, Alp);
        //stroke(10, 10, 10, Alp);
    }else{
        stroke(10, 10, 10, Alp);
        //stroke(50, 100, 100, Alp);
    }

  }

  Ellipse();

}


void Math() {
  Dstep = 20; //determinar aqui el diametro que queramos alcanzar
  Astep = 100/N1;
}

void Ellipse() {

  ellipse(width/2, height/2, N2*12, N2*12);
  //strokeWeight(N2/7+0.5); 

  if (N2>N1) {         //se añade cuando se cumple se cambia el tamaño
    strokeWeight(10);
  }else if (N2<1){
    //strokeWeight(N2/7+0.5);
    strokeWeight(2);
  }


  //println("N2:"+N2);

}
```